# Improve this function that compares jQuery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me improve this function that compares the jQuery version currently available <sup>(or not)</sup> with the one required.

```
function(need) {
    if (typeof(jQuery) != 'undefined') {
        if (!need) return true;
        var re = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/,
            cur = re.exec(jQuery.fn.jquery),
            need = re.exec(need);
        return (need[1] <= cur[1] && need[2] <= cur[2] && need[3] <= cur[3]);
    } else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, but that code is completely broken.

- It doesn't work if either version contains only two numbers such as the current "1.6".
- It uses string comparison instead of integer comparison, so that it will return `true` if you "need" (theoretical) version "1.4.10" but only "1.4.2" is included, because `"10" < "2"` is `true`.
- It doesn't stop comparing minor version numbers, if the major number is already bigger. For example it will return `false` if "1.4.2" is "needed", but "1.5.1" is included, because `"2" > "1"`
- And finally you should keep in mind that "newer" isn't necessarily better. For example, the new 1.6 version changes how `.attr()` works, and scripts that rely on the old functionality of `.attr()` may break.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a plugin.

```
$.versioncompare(version1[, version2 = jQuery.fn.jquery])
```

https://github.com/zuzara/jQuery-version-compare-plugin

Answer (score -1):

I feel like I'm missing something, but I got it down to one line for a compressed version, or a few lines for a verbose explination.

**Compressed version:**

```
(parseInt(jQuery.fn.jquery.split('.').join('')) > 140) ? alert("Running jquery greater than 1.4.0") : alert("current jquery version is 1.4.0 or less");
```

**Long version for clarity:**

```
// get version as a string and get rid of the periods. 
version = jQuery.fn.jquery.split('.').join('');

// Make into one long number for easy comparison.  Example, 171, or 141.
version = parseInt(version);
if(version > 141){
  alert("We're using a version greater than 1.4.1");
}else{
  alert("jQuery version is 1.4.1 or lower");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just as broken. It only works for two versions with the same number of parts and if those part only have 1 digit part. Examples: It will falsely conclude that "1.5" < "1.4.1" and "1.10" < "1.9".